# How to write Array of Hashed with json

Tags: json, chef-infra

I want to use a array of hashed in chef's node json file.

So I tried like this, but this causes only a parse error.

```
"users": [
{"name": "user1",
 "password":"user1_shadowed_password"
},
{"name": "user2",
 "password":"user2_shadowed_password"
}
]
```

How can I write a Array of Hashes with json format?

Comment: array.map { |x| Hash[x.each_pair.to_x] }.to_json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi your JSON seems correct you just need to enclose it with {}.
To verify your JSON you could use this site..
http://jsonlint.com/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are that you forgot to add a comma either at the end of the block that you added, or on the block immediately before the users block before it.

It's also worth noting that json, unlike ruby, does not allow for "spare" commas at the end of lists.